# python IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, list, indexing, range, out

I'm trying to create a matrix from the folowing board, with the first item as coordinate (0,0) with the following code, but I keep getting a list index out of range error... Can someone help me out or correct how I should preceed?

```
board_5x = ['orange', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'red',
            'orange', 'blue', 'orange', 'orange', 'yellow',
            'blue', 'orange', 'blue', 'red', 'green',
            'yellow', 'orange', 'green', 'orange', 'red',
            'orange', 'blue', 'yellow', 'red', 'green',
            'red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'blue', 'yellow',
            'green', 'orange', 'orange', 'green', 'green',
            'orange', 'green', 'red', 'red', 'green',
            'orange', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'red', 'orange',
            'red', 'green', 'blue', 'blue', 'orange']


board=[]

for row in range(10):
    for col in range(5):      
        board[row][col]=board_5x[row*5+col]
print board
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't placed values in `board`, so you might as well go ahead and build it with the new values in one pass with a comprehension:

```
board = [[board_5x[row*5+col] for col in range(5)] for row in range(10)]
```